# How to move the connectors along with objects in Keynote?

Tags: keynote, animation

I have two objects: a circle and a square. There is a connector line connecting these two objects. I want to move the square from one point to another using the action>move animation. However, I want the connector to stay connected during the move animation. Let the connector grow or shrink if required. Is this possible?

As a workaround, is it possible to animate just the connector? I want one end to stay fixed in a point, the other end should be moved to a different point.

Comment: select and make it a group

Comment: If i make the connector and the object as a group and try to move the group, the connector's other end point doesn't stay connected anymore. The entire group moves around.